# Handle status in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I have following in angular 7.

```
public deleteId(pId){
    return this.http.delete<any>(this.deleteUrl(pId), {observe: 'response'})
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

Delete method (I want 202 code here in response.status)

```
public deleteMethod(): void {
    this.service.deleteId(this.id)
      .subscribe(response => {

       console.log(`Delete response ` , response);

        if(response.status === 200) {
          console.log('Deleted successfully');
        }
       else if(response.status === 202) {
          console.log('something else'); // I am not getting response.status here
        }
    });
  }
```

I am getting status code 200 properly but, 202 i am getting in `handleError` method. I want 202 as a response. How can i get that?

```
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  //It sends me to this function.
}
```

Comment: Can you include what the `error` variable contains in the `handleResponse` method in the event of a 202 status?

Comment: @Igor What do you mean? I think this you are asking for`response.status`

Comment: @ketan it's really unclear what you are asking. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @PaoloCasciello I edited. When i run application API called and if response status is 202 it send me to `handleError` function instead of `.subscribe(response`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got solution with following:

```
public deleteId(pId){
    return this.http.delete<any>(this.deleteUrl(pId), {observe: 'response', responseType: 'text' as 'json'})
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
 }
```

Added `, responseType: 'text' as 'json'`

Answer (score -1):

```
public deleteMethod(): void {
this.service.deleteId(this.id)
  .subscribe(response => {

   console.log(`Delete response ` , response);

    if(response.status === 200) {
      console.log('Deleted successfully');
    }
  },
  err => {
    console.log(err.status); // ----> Here's your error
    if(err.status === 202) {
      // do your stuff
    }
  }
);
```

}

Comment: No. I want 202 in response, as it's success status code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43683052/get-status-code-http-get-response-angular2 that should be the answer u are searching for