# how can i fetech the status_code 400 in angular

Tags: angular

I want to check if the status code=400 in angular so I can fetch a notif

I've tried this -

```js
signUp() {
    let body =
    {
        login: this.username,
        nom: this.nom,
        prenom: this.prenom,
        adress: this.adress,
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
        date_naissance: this.datenaissance,
        num_tel: this.numTel,
    }

    this.signappService.newsignup(body).subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
            console.log(res)
            this.sucess = true;
            this.failed = false;
        },
        (err) => {
            console.warn(err)
            if (err.status == 400) {
                this.failed = true;
                this.sucess = false;
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? Is it not working, or showing any error?

Comment: it not showing any error even in my console i have the err status 400

Comment: Are you sure that your backend invoked by this.signappService.newsignup(body) is actualy producing a 400 status response. Have you tried console.log'ing what err is?

Comment: yeah i am sure i did the error by purpose in my trials so the notif apperas

Comment: yeah i am sure i did the error by purpose in my trials so the notif apperas

Answer (score -2):

Hello after a short research I found this answear:
[Get status code http.get response angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43683052/get-status-code-http-get-response-angular2/46937803)
Did you set "{observe: 'response'}" in newsignup from signappService?

Comment: To my knowledge, you'll only need that if you want to inspect response codes form successful HTTP requests. The catchError-operator (or error-callback of the subscribe method) will return an EventError or HttpErrorResponse.