# How can get the status code of the HttpClient module in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http, angular-httpclient

How to get the status code of all the request using `HttpClient`

```
apiCall() {
    let header1 = new HttpHeaders();
    header1 = header1.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    header1 = header1.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.token}`);

    this.http.post("URL",
      {
        "dataSentHere": "data"
      }, {
      headers: header1
    }).subscribe(data => {

      console.log(data);

    },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.status === 403) {
         console.log("403 status code caught");
        }
      }

      
    )
  }
```

How to get the status code of the http request which returns 202 , 200 etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get status code http.get response angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43683052/get-status-code-http-get-response-angular2)

Comment: still how to print the status code which is 200, 201, 205 etc

Comment: literally the first answer of the mentioned post shows how to print the status code

Answer (score 4):

Use `HttpErrorResponse` and `HttpResponse` from `'@angular/common/http'`

```
apiCall() {
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers = headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.token}`);

  this.http.post<HttpResponse<any>>('URL', { data }, { headers }).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response.status) // log status code
  }, (e: HttpErrorResponse) => console.log(e.status))

}
```

Comment: how i can i add the headers ??
i cant add more than 3 arguments

Comment: The 3rd argument should be an object that has headers as a property. I expanded the above logic.

Comment: The third parameter of http.post() has to be { headers, observe: 'response' }.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `observe: 'response'` to the options parameter. By doing this you would have the whole response available in your subscription.

```
  public apiCall(): void {
    let header1: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    header1 = header1.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    header1 = header1.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.token}`);

    this.http.post<HttpResponse<any>>(
      'URL',
      {
        dataSentHere: 'data',
      },
      {
        headers: header1,
        observe: 'response',
      },
    ).subscribe(
      (data: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        if (data.status === 200 || data.status === 202) {
          console.log(`Got a successfull status code: ${data.status}`);
        }
        console.log(`This contains body: ${data.body}`);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.status === 403) {
          console.error('403 status code caught');
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Answer (score 0):

If your using HttpClient, here is an example:

```
this.http.post(myRequest, body, { headers : myHeaders, observe: 'response' }).subscribe(
  data => {
    console.warn(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  },
  error => {
    console.error(error.errorMessege);
});
```