# How to get the response status of an http request?

Tags: angular, http, httpclient

I have a small piece of code that I use to call a service and do a `post` request. The fact is that I need to get the status of the response from the request. The fact is that I subscribe to a request from the service and I need to type it specifically for my application and I cannot get the status. Tell me what am I doing wrong?

In component

```
this.service.sendParams(constConnectBody).subscribe((profile: IProfile) => {
   this.profile = profile;
}, (res) => console.log(res.status)); // nothing
```

In service

```
public sendParams(body: any):Observable<any> {
   return this.httpClient.post<any>(`this.url`, body)
}
```

or in the service

```
responseStatus: any

public sendParams(body: any):Observable<any> {
   return this.httpClient.post<any>(`this.url`, body, {observe: response}).pipe(map(res => this.responseStatus = res.status))
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 4.3.3 HttpClient : How get value from the header of a response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505619/angular-4-3-3-httpclient-how-get-value-from-the-header-of-a-response)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get status code http.get response angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43683052/get-status-code-http-get-response-angular2)

Comment: @mbojko, no. i have my typed answer. Can you answer to my question in answer below?

Comment: @Zerotwelve, i have my typed answer. Can you answer to my question in answer below?

Comment: @NaraGameme what do you mean by " I need to type it" ?

Comment: @Zerotwelve `.subscribe((profile: IProfile)` not a just `.subscribe((response => )`

Answer (score 4):

The HttpClient methods accept an options parameter which can include `observe: 'response'` to return the full response rather than just the response body.

`return this.httpClient.post<any>('this.url', body, {observe: 'response'})`

See https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#options for details

Comment: Thank you) And in the component, first code, where I call my service method, what should I write to get status response?

Answer (score 0):

based on your comments you can do it like this

```js
responseStatus: any

public sendParams(body: any):Observable<IProfile> {
   return this.httpClient.post<IProfile>(this.url, body, {observe: 'response'}).pipe(map(res => {
      this.responseStatus = res.status;
      return res.body;
   }));
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you) One more question: why i got nothing in the console log, when i call the my variable response status in component?

Comment: you your code: `.subscribe((profile: IProfile) => {this.profile = profile;}, (res) => console.log(res.status)); // nothing` (res) is the error case not the satatus code. Please read more about obsevables https://rxjs.dev/