# unable to access 200 code status in angular server response

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, mongodb

Goal: If the server response with 200 code, I want to perform some changes on the record locally.

issue: I am not able to access the response code or the 'message' attribute

this is how the server response from this http call::

```
// MongooseModelSchema: this is the model that uses moongose 
    MongooseModelSchema.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id, creator: req.userData.userId }, channel)
      .then(result => {
        if (result.n > 0) {
          res.status(200).json({ message: "Update successful!" }); // this is what I want to capture
        } else {
          res.status(401).json({ message: "Not authorized!" });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({
          message: "Couldn't udpate channel!"
        });
      });
```

I am able to hit the API no problem

I have the following http snip in my angular code::

```
    this.http
      .put(BACKEND_URL+'setState/' + id, channelData)
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log('response',response);
        console.log('check if response has Update successful!: ',JSON.stringify(response).search('Update successful!'));
        console.log('response.message',response.message);

       this.router.navigate(["/editChannel", id]);
      })
```

this is the console.log image:
[image: consolelog image]

issue image: as you can see, i dont have access to the return code. I also cant access the 'message' property UNTIL i run the code, then it works.... super weird.

[image: error on message property]

How do I check for the 200 code?

Comment: you can check this for status code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43683052/get-status-code-http-get-response-angular2

Answer (score 1):

That makes sense. Message object is not typed, so compiler is telling you that `message` doesn't exist on response. Instead what you should do is the following:

myresponse.ts:

```
interface MyResponse {
 message: string
}

this.http
      .put<MyResponse>(BACKEND_URL+'setState/' + id, channelData)
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log('response',response);
        console.log('check if response has Update successful!: ',JSON.stringify(response).search('Update successful!'));
        console.log('response.message',response.message);

       this.router.navigate(["/editChannel", id]);
      })
```

now angular will grab the response and map it to the `MyResponse` interface giving you ability to access the `message` property. Alternatively you could keep it as `any` or `unknown` not sure what the type on response by default is, but if its `any` just do `response['message']`

Hope that helps.